# Django: set views, urls and templates for objects in categories/foreignkey

Tags: python, django

I have created models with categories, subcategories and sub-subcategories. I have had a lot of problems getting it to work. 
My models.py:

```
class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'school_name', unique = True)
...      
class Department(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = 'department_name', unique = True)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
...
class Professor(models.Model):
    Professor_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
...
```

My views.py:

```
def department_list(request, category_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(School, slug = category_slug)
    schools = School.objects.filter(school_name = category)
    departments = Department.objects.filter(school = category)
    context = {'schools':schools, 'departments': departments}
    return render(request, 'main/department_list.html', context)    

def professor_list(request, category_slug, department_slug):
    category = get_object_or_404(School, slug = category_slug)
    subcategory = get_object_or_404(Department, slug = department_slug)
    schools = School.objects.filter(school_name = category)
    departments = Department.objects.filter(school = category)
    Professors = Professor.objects.filter(department = subcategory)
    context = {'Professors ': Professors}
    return render(request, 'main/Professor_list.html', context)

class DepartmentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Department
    fields = ['department_name']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        school = get_object_or_404(School, pk=self.kwargs['school_id'])
        kwargs['school'] = school
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        school = get_object_or_404(School, pk=self.kwargs['school_id'])
        form.instance.school = school
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<category_slug>/', views.department_list, name = 'departments'),
    path('<category_slug>/<department_slug>/', views.professor_list, name = 
         'Professors'),
    path('<category_slug>/new/', DepartmentCreateView.as_view(), name = 
         'department-create'),
]
```

My department_list view works but the professor_list and DepartmentCreateView seem to fail forever. I have tried looking everywhere but can't seem to figure out why. Can someone please give me suggestions? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: "Fail forever" *how*? What error do you get? What do you see?

Comment: My page for some reason has stopped showing me the error. It just says, "A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator." The command line says, " File "C:\Users\bbchen33\.virtualenvs\Djangoweb-LasqhaLs\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.py", line 332, in get_traceback_html
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 9735: illegal multibyte sequence"